# different behavior of static_cast and dynamic_cast in a specific scenario

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, dynamic-cast, static-cast

I don't figure out the real difference between static_cast and dynamic_cast in below scenario:

```
                                **///with static_cast///**
    class Foo{};
    class Bar: public Foo
    {
        public:
          void func()
          {
            return;
          }
    };

    int main(int argc, char** argv)
    {
        Foo* f = new Foo;
        Bar* b = static_cast<Bar*>(f);
        b->func();
        return 0;
    }
```

> Output:
>
> Successfully Build and Compiled!

```
                                **///with dynamic_cast///**
    class Foo{};
    class Bar: public Foo
    {
        public:
          void func()
          {
            return;
          }
    };

    int main(int argc, char** argv)
    {
        Foo* f = new Foo;
        Bar* b = dynamic_cast<Bar*>(f);
        b->func();
        return 0;
    }
```

> Output:
>
> main.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)': main.cpp:26:34: error:
>   cannot dynamic_cast 'f' (of type 'class Foo*') to type 'class Bar*'
>   (source type is not polymorphic)
>        Bar* b = dynamic_cast(f);

I'd be appreciated if someone could help me understand this!

Comment: While the first builds and runs, it will lead to *undefined behavior*, because `f` (and therefore `b`) isn't a pointer to a `Bar` object.

Comment: As for `dynamic_cast`, [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast) should be helpful.

Comment: You can't cast a pointer to a base class object to a derived class pointer. `dynamic_cast` (in case of virtual members) will return `nullptr`. `static_cast` will compile but using such pointer will result in undefined behavior.

Comment: @DanielLangr Such cast itself is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The hint is in the part

> (source type is not polymorphic)

It means, for `dynamic_cast` to work, it needs a polymorphic base class, i.e. have a virtual method

```
class Foo {
public:
    virtual ~Foo() {}
};
```

---

Apart from that, it will not work, because `f` does not point to a `Bar` object. `dynamic_cast` will return a nullptr in this case, which you must check

```
Foo* f = new Foo;
Bar* b = dynamic_cast<Bar*>(f);
if (b != nullptr)
    b->func();
```

Comment: Just to expand on this a bit: The main reason the polymorphic base class is required is to perform this run time check. A lesser reason is to enable downcasting over a `virtual` inheritance relation. `static_cast` cannot handle this latter case because the offset of the base class subobject is not fixed among the derived class and all its further derived classes.